# Execution order of protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

Which is the best way to control the execution order of Protractor tests?

Problem case 1: protractor swipes angular pages so quickly that it cannot manipulate (fill in) input data. (The swipe logic is to transfer from being invisible to visible and by translating them into the window visible area). thus protractor cannot see those beyond the window and with opacity 0. To test i can only fill in the first page. the others are swiped too fast (or async).

Problem case 2: After i filled in the first page and submitted the form, the data is saved and alert shows confirmation message. Then protractor has to click a drop-down list and browser should navigate to the page where saved data is displayed. The problem is that protractor clicks the drop-down list before the data is saved due to alert fired later (have to wait for alert).

Question is: Is there a way to control tests to be executed in the given order in protractor? And is there a way to hold down swiping to fill in the date (otherwise protractor does not see it)? Here is the simplified code:

```
    it('should fill in form and send data', function() {

            // fill in textarea field
            element.all(by.css('textarea')).first().clear().sendKeys('test');

            // goes to page 2
            browser.executeScript("angular.element(document.documentElement)
.injector().get('$rootScope').$broadcast('nextPage', {direction: 'next'});");

            // Here is Problem 1. Though i can see this page when testing, 
            // the input is not visible for protractor.
            // fill in input-field
            element.all(by.css('input')).first().clear().sendKeys('test');     

           // goes to page 1
            browser.executeScript("angular.element(document.documentElement)
.injector().get('$rootScope').$broadcast('prevPage', {direction: 'prev'});");


            // submit form
            element(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click();

            // Here is problem 2. The following test is executed earlier
            // than the following alert.
            //browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 3000);
            var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
            expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Saved');
            alertDialog.accept();

        });


it('should click drop-down-list', function() {
    // click drop-down list
    element(by.css('.drop-down-list')).click();
});
```

Comment: add a wait between your test

Comment: Dear Emna, This extra wait blocks alert and alert is never shown. Or I am doing something wrong. Could you please show a working code sample?

Comment: I even tried browser.controlFlow().timeout(3000); but it also blocks alert. May be I should consider browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
        browser.controlFlow().execute(test);
    }); but do not know how to pass spect into it so that they should be seen.

Comment: add `browser.sleep(3000);`

Comment: As I add browser.sleep(3000) to the second test, it just freezes the whole testing and when testing resumes all the same happens.

Comment: also tried variations with var contFlow = function(fn) {
            var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
            flow.execute(function () {
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            });
            flow.execute(fn);
            flow.execute(function () {
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
            });
        }; but no luck. Have to give up.

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe browser.sleep(5000) should resolve the second issue.

if not can you try with promisies

```
 element(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click().then(function(){
  var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
  expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Saved');
  alertDialog.accept();
});
```

This should wait for the promise to get resolved (i.e to click submit button) and then execute the code snippet inside